# What is the difference between feature provided by EJB server and EJB container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm trying understand the EJB's concept, but it's so fuzzy.
I read about EJB server and EJB container, and that EJB container runs within EJB server. I also know that both provide resources/services, it's at this time that appears my question...

What are the resources/services provided by each?

Thanks so much everybody by help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **"EJB Server"**

In short, "EJB Server" is just a label for any [Application Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server) that has a EJB implementation. The correct definition for it would be [Java EE Server](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/overview004.htm#BNABQ).

For example, both Glassfish and JBossAS have each one its own EJB container. For that reason some people call them "EJB Servers". [This page](http://java-source.net/open-source/ejb-servers) have a list of "EJB Servers" and they are called like that because they implement a EJB specification which implies the existence of the EJB Container.

But it is not a formal definition, more like a soft convention.

> **EJB Container**

Now this is the actual EJB service provider that does all the work. It gives you application services such as transaction control an security, and it follows the defined [EJB Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/).

When you deploy Session Beans, the EJB Container is responsible for its life cycle, its transaction, injection, among other tasks. Details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans).

From the [official source](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/overview004.htm#BNABQ):

> EJB container: Manages the execution of enterprise beans for Java EE
>   applications. Enterprise beans and their container run on the Java EE
>   server.

Now that I made some context definition, lets try to answer your question:

> **What are the resources/services provided by each?**

"**EJB Server**"

The "EJB Server" provides a EJB Container. Thats it. As my early statement, it is just a label, not a formal definition. In most cases what you have is a Java EE Server like Glassfish, which end up giving you much more services than only EJB, like encription, Web Container, etc.

If we stick to this logic, a server like Glassfish can also be called:

- Servlet Server
- Web Server
- JMS Server
- JSP Server
- etc

Can you see where this is going?

**EJB Container**

The EJB Container implementation provides the resources and services defined by the EJB Specification. For instance, it has transaction management according to the specification.

There are a lot of technologies or terms that may have different meanings depending on the context. Web Services and SOA are some examples.